# Search form to query on external site + parameter by the end

Tags: php, html, forms

I have search form on my site which is going to search results on external site. But I want to add an anchor in this link, so now I have form:

```
<form method=get action="http://externalsite.com" target="_blank">
<input type=text name=q value="">
<input type=submit value="lets go">
</form>
```

And my form going to: http://externalsite.com/?q=SEARCH_PHRASE

I want url like: http://externalsite.com/?q=SEARCH_PHRASE#anchor
How add this "#anchor" by the form?

Comment: You can submit using `Jquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the anchor to the `action` attribute of your form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://externalsite.com#anchor" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="lets go">
</form>
```

Comment: That's it! But I have another problem. My query looks like:
"?pl_wyniki-wyszukiwania,17&sPhrase=SEARCH_PHRASE#anchor"
but after redirect from form there's a problem because link is broken and search doesn't work:
"?pl_wyniki-wyszukiwania%2C17%26sPhrase=test#s "

Comment: If that answers your original question you should mark it as the accepted answer. For your other question, I have no idea what you mean!